# Get connection type with knex

Tags: mysql, node.js, typescript, postgresql, knex.js

I'm writing an application that supports MySQL and Postgres at the same time, using Knex.

For certain features the query builder doesn't cut it, and I need to write a MySQL or Postgres specific query.

What I'm looking for is a syntax such as this:

```js
switch(knex.type) {

  case 'mysql' :
    knex.raw('...');
    break;
  case 'pg' :
    knex.raw('...');
    break;

}
```

I can't seem to find if there's a way to do this. Not in the documentation or in the types (so far). Is this possible?

Comment: I think that it is better to create 2 instances of knex, one for mysql and the other for pg.
This way it will build the proper query without the need to distinguish.

Comment: My service only connects to 1 database at a time, it just supports multiple database types. So I'll ultimately still need *some* way to see which one I'm connected to.